# XML file not recieving String[] for ListView

Tags: java, android, xml, android-listview, scroll

I am new to android programming and am taking Udacity's courses to learn. They have me making a scrollable list of Strings using the ArrayAdapter and Listview, but the data inside my java class is not being passed through. Android studio shows the template of a list, and when I launch the app, I get a blank screen. The XML code that is supposed to receive the data is below, and it's called fragment_main.xml

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivityFragment"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/fragment_main_textview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</FrameLayout>
```

The java class that it takes from (MainActivityFragment) is written in short below. The method I have created is called onCreateView()

```
public class MainActivityFragment extends Fragment {
private ArrayAdapter<String> data;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container);
    String[] daysForecast = {"Monday-Sunny-83/95", "Tuesday-Sunny-83/95",
                                "Wednesday-Rainy-67/75",
                                "Tuesday-Partly Cloudy-78/83",
                                "Friday-Rainy-56/65", "Saturday-Dim-34/43",
                                "Sunday-Awesome-70/78"
    };
    data = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
            R.layout.fragment_main, R.id.fragment_main_textview, daysForecast);
    ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(
            R.id.fragment_main_textview);
    listView.setAdapter(data);
    return rootView;
}
```

}

When I try to launch the app on my phone, I am told that the app has crashed. Additionally, Android studio does not display the string array in the display screen, but instead displays the template associated with initializing a list. Is my error in here, or in some other part of my code? Thanks.

EDIT: Here is some additional code inside the project

### MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if(savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new MainActivityFragment()).commit();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

### activity_main.xml

```
<FrameLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.family.sunshine.app.MainActivity">
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't pass the `fragment_main.xml` to `ArrayAdapter` constructor.

replace

```
 data = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
        R.layout.fragment_main, R.id.fragment_main_textview, daysForecast);
```

by

Edit: try it may be it solve your problem.

```
 data = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),R.id.fragment_main_textview,android.R.id.text1,daysForecast);
```

OR visit [here!](https://www.caveofprogramming.com/guest-posts/simple-listview-using-arrayadapter.html)

Comment: I tried this but array adapter seems to need fragment_main to create data. It needs all those parameters

Comment: can you post every thing you did?

Comment: Alright I posted two more files. Hope this helps. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, this didn't work. I actually learned that I needed to add the Fragment to MainActivity.java, inside its onCreate class. I have since updated that file and the activity_main.xml file, but the screen is still showing blank. I've updated the code in the question to reflect the current state of my project.

Comment: replace, 
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container);
with,
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,false);

is it possible for you to send me project, so i'll debug it with me.

Comment: I've actually found the solution for my problem. If you are curious, you can see the answer below. Thank you so much for helping!

Answer (score 0):

Here was the issue: MainActivityFragment was not connected to MainActivity.java, so the fragment was never visible. This is what it should have looked like:

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    String[] daysForecast = {"Monday-Sunny-83/95", "Tuesday-Sunny-83/95",
            "Wednesday-Rainy-67/75",
            "Tuesday-Partly Cloudy-78/83",
            "Friday-Rainy-56/65", "Saturday-Dim-34/43",
            "Sunday-Awesome-70/78", "more data", "more data", "more data",
            "more data", "more data!!!!", "more data????", "end"
    };
    data = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.my_new_resource,
            R.id.forecast_view, daysForecast);
    ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(
            R.id.fragment_main_textview);
    listView.setAdapter(data);
return rootView;
}
```

Additionally, the ArrayAdapter was supposed to incorporate a THIRD XML file, the syntax of which is shown below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:id="@+id/forecast_view" />
```